# KNockoutJS - Bootstrap modal not loading correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

working on a project to get a CRUD system built with knockoutJS  and I get my data from an AJAX call. Still working on the add and delete functionalities at the moment but currently having issues with my modal. It dosent seem to be showing my modal form even tought it seems like it's trying. It dosent seem to throwing me any errors.

I replicated the issue in this jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rqwku4kb/28/. Ive looked at the code several times but im not quite certain where the issue might be. I doublechecked that my bootstrap, jquery and knockout are loaded correctly.

Would anyone know what im missing?

```
ko.bindingHandlers.modal = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        $(element).modal({
            show: false
        });

        var value = valueAccessor();
        if (typeof value === 'function') {
            $(element).on('hide.bs.modal', function() {
               value(false);
            });
        }
        ko.utils.domNodeDisposal.addDisposeCallback(element, function () {
           $(element).modal("destroy");
        });

    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var value = valueAccessor();
        if (ko.utils.unwrapObservable(value)) {
            $(element).modal('show');

        } else {
            $(element).modal('hide');
        }
    }
}

/* global ko, $ */
function Incident(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.ID = data.ID;
    self.Description = ko.observable(data.Description);
    self.Incident = ko.observable(data.Incident);
    self.Composante = ko.observable(data.Composante);
    self.available_composante = ko.observableArray(["A","B","C","D","E"]);
        self.chosen_composante = ko.observableArray();
}

Incident.BASE_URL = '../../../../_vti_bin/listData.svc/PROD_Incidents';
Incident.CREATE_HEADERS = {
    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose"
};
Incident.UPDATE_HEADERS = {
    "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
    "If-Match": "*"
};

Incident.prototype.save = function() {
    var id = this.ID,
        url = Incident.BASE_URL + (id ? '(' + encodeURIComponent(id) + ')' : '');

    return $.ajax(url, {
        type: id ? "MERGE" : "POST",
        data: ko.toJS({
            Description: this.Description,
            Incident: this.Incident
        }),
        processData: false,
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        headers: id ? Incident.UPDATE_HEADERS : Incident.CREATE_HEADERS,
    });
};

function IncidentList(data) {
    var self = this;
    self.incidents = ko.observableArray();
    self.currentIncident = ko.observable();
    self.showDialog = ko.observable(false);

    self.ShowMeTheCurrentSelectedIncident = function(data) {
        self.currentIncident();
        data.chosen_composante.push(data.Composante);
        self.showDialog(true);  
    };

    self.clearCurrentIncident = function() {
        self.currentIncident(null);
    };

    // list filter & automatic loading
    self.filter = ko.observable("");
    self.orderby = ko.observable("");
    self.params = ko.computed(function() {
        return ko.toJS({
            $filter: self.filter,
            $orderby: self.orderby
        });
    }).extend({
        rateLimit: 100
    });
    self.params.subscribe(self.load, self);

    // let inital load happen immediately
    self.params.notifySubscribers();
}

IncidentList.prototype.load = function(params) {
    var self = this;
    return $.get(Incident.BASE_URL, params).then(function(data) {
        if (data.d.results) {
            self.incidents(data.d.results.map(function(item) {
                return new Incident(item);
            }));
        } else {
            console.log("no results received from server");
        }
    }).fail(function() {
        console.log("error", arguments);
    });
};

// viewmodel setup
var vm = new IncidentList();
vm.filter("ÉtatValue ne 'Fermé'");
vm.orderby("PrioritéValue desc");

// binding when document is ready
$(function() {
    ko.applyBindings(vm);
});

// Ajax mockup
$.mockjax({
    url: Incident.BASE_URL,
    contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
    responseText: {
        d: {
            results: [{
                ID: "123",
                Description: "The server x is unavailable",
                Incident: "1234",
                Composante: "A, "
            }, {
                ID: "124",
                Description: "The router located downtown is down",
                Incident: "12345",
                Composante: "B"
            }, {
                ID: "125",
                Description: "Fiber optic cable downtown is flapping",
                Incident: "123456",
                Composante: "C"
            }, {
                ID: "126",
                Description: "Network unvailable at the beaver site",
                Incident: "1234567",
                Composante: "D"
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Please, include an entire but *minimal* repro in the question itself. Currently you have not enough in there to reproduce the issue (i.e. the view stuff is missing), as well as too much in there (for sure not *all* of that code is needed to repro the issue). See "[mcve]" for guidance.

Comment: PS. You're not setting `currentIncident` in the Edit click handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Jeroen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/419956/jeroen) noticed above, you should set the the currentIncident like this:

```
self.ShowMeTheCurrentSelectedIncident = function(data) {
 self.currentIncident(data);
 data.chosen_composante.push(data.Composante);
 self.showDialog(true); 
};
```

See the update: http://jsfiddle.net/rqwku4kb/29/

Comment: I have updated slightly for clearing backdrop http://jsfiddle.net/skhatoon/tLqsfap8/1/